# How to change the color of highlighted html tags in PhpStorm 10?

Tags: phpstorm

No matter how hard I search I can't find the way to change this blue highlighted color when the caret is on a html element. How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: Please show the screenshot using Default color scheme. Yours is a custom one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the menu, follow these commands:

`Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`, `Code/Matched brace` `background color`

Comment: In later versions it has changed slightly to Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General, Code > Matched brace > background color

Comment: Thank you, that dark blue made reading code really difficult!